# animation in java: paint() and repaint() or threads

Tags: java, animation, applet, paint

I would like to know which method should I choose when trying to create an animated game in java. Basically I have a 9x9 matrix; some of the slots of the matrix are filled with 2D figures such as hexagons or circles. some of the figures are moved to different slots or are animated (rotation when clicked or resizing..).

My question would be, in this case should I use only paint() and repaint() to simulate the animation and movement of the figures(in this case I would have to redraw every time the static elements of the matrix?) or is it recommended to use threads and the runnable interface.

I hope my question isn't too vague. I'm looking forward to your advice.Thanks.

Comment: Threads don't have anything to do with animation, so even if you use threads and runnables, you're still going to have to make painting calls. I'd suggest taking a look at [Killer Game Programming in Java](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/)

Comment: Threads have *everything* to do with animation. Often (as the accepted answer points out) the friendly `Timer` class is used to simplify your code, but behind the scenes, you've still just got a thread advancing your time variables and calling `repaint()`. You can't do animation without using a thread dedicated to the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One commonly used approach is to call `repaint()` from the `ActionListener` of a Swing `Timer`.